# Read a file purely in javascript on Firefox OS(B2G)

Tags: javascript, file, firefox-os, b2g

I have to read a file from the file system of my phone. Essentially its to check if the file contains a word. The file is located in the /sys folder of my phone. I know I can get the contents of the File using FileReader.readAsText(file) to get the contents as a string and then parse it for the word. But how do I make the "file" object to pass to the FileReader object. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Just wanted to add here:

Can I use the File constructor here?

var file = File("/path/to/file");

Comment: You can't read a file directory from the file system - a user has to select the file and place it in a <input type="file">. You can then read the file using FileReader

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api

Comment: The problem is that this code is a part of a controller file for gecko. It doesnt have any related HTML file. And I need to read just one file in whose path can be hardcoded.

Comment: Could you tell exactly which file in `/sys/` you're trying to open? Maybe there is a different solution using API that can get the values you're trying to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

You can only read data from your app folder (via XMLHttpRequest) and from the SD Card. You cannot read data from any other place in a Firefox OS app.